# 3D Figure 8 Torus in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, mesh

This is the code to a 3d torus I have generated.

```
ezmesh('(3.7+0.5*cos(v))*cos(u)','(3.7+ 0.5*cos(v))*sin(u)','0.5*sin(v)',[0,2*pi,0,2*pi])
axis([-7 7 -7 7 -2 2]);
```

Can anyone show me how to transform this torus code into a figure 8 torus? These are the equations and parameters I want to use. I'm not sure how to adjust the parameters in the original torus so the code will work out.

```
%Figure Eight Torus
%Parameters: c = 1, -pi <= u, v <= pi
%Equations: x = (cos(u)*( c + sin(v)*cos(u)) - (sin(2*v)*sin(u)/2))
%           y = (sin(u)*(c + sin(v)*cos(u)) - (sin(2*v)*sin(u)/2))
%           z = s(in(u)*sin(v)) + (cos(u)*sin(2*v)/2)
```

Thank you in advance.
-Thomas

Comment: Why did you just [repeat your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20648469/2065121)?

Comment: Have you tried to rework your first code there using your equations? At least show an attempt at that.

Comment: c=1;
u=-pi:0.25:pi
v=-pi:0.25:pi
ezmesh('(cos(u)*( c + sin(v)*cos(u)) - (sin(2*v)*sin(u)/2))','(sin(u)*(c + sin(v)*cos(u)) - (sin(2*v)*sin(u)/2))','(sin(u)*sin(v)) + (cos(u)*sin(2*v)/2)')'

Comment: Sorry about the commenting errors, I just joined today and I am learning how to use this website.

Comment: I plugged in the equations into the ezmesh, however I cannot figure out how to adjust the parameters for 'u' and 'v'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
ezmesh('cos(u)*(1+sin(v)*cos(u))-(sin(2.*v))*(sin(u)/2)',...
       'sin(u)*((1+sin(v)*cos(u))-(sin(2.*v))*(sin(u)/2))',...
       'sin(u)*sin(v)+(cos(u)*(sin(2.*v))/2)',[-pi,3,-3,pi]);

axis([-4 4 -4 4 -4 4])
```